How to make a proper choice section?
I'm trying to write a basic choice system, though I am having issues.
PChoice = input("What is your choice?: ")
RootChoice = input("Are you sure?:")
if input == "yes" or "Yes":
if RootChoice == "no" or "No":
 print("Please choose again")
 print("You Chose " + PChoice)

I can't seem to figure out how to get it to only print either the yes line or no line (You chose, Please choose again)
I'm sorry if this is basic, This is my first solo developing project.
I was trying to write code that would print one option if chosen, I tried to write a if not command but that didn't work.

Have you tried using else ? It should simply allow you to run either cases.

Please start with the [tour] and read [ask]. In particular, be specific with what doesn't work with the code you provided. It's already relatively small, but in many cases it's also useful to extract a [mcve] nonetheless. For Python, also indent your code with the customary four spaces, please. It makes it easier for others to read.

Also try using .lower or .upper for the input rather than "yes" or "Yes", makes the code more efficient and accepts all capital and lower combinations for the input, like "yEs" etc.

This Python script asks the user for a choice, confirms it, and responds based on the user's confirmation. If the user confirms with "yes," it acknowledges their choice; if "no," it prompts them to choose again. Invalid inputs result in an error message asking for a "yes" or "no" answer.

PChoice = input("What is your choice?: ")
RootChoice = input("Are you sure? (yes/no): ").strip().lower()
if RootChoice == "yes":
    confirmation_message = f"You chose {PChoice}"
elif RootChoice == "no":
    confirmation_message = "Please choose again"
else:
    confirmation_message = "Invalid response. Please answer 'yes' or 'no'."
print(confirmation_message)


